# Rules and practices for order of parameter sets in Scala functions

Tags: scala, function, methods, parameters, currying

Assume there is a function `foo` that should compute some return value `R` on the input value `T` by delegating some of the work to some other function being passed as parameter.

For example, one could define it as such:
`def foo(data: List[T], delegate: T => R): List[R]`

However, if I want to reuse either my function with data, or with delegate, I cannot, so I could split them into separate parameter sets, like this:
`def foo(data: List[T])(delegate: T => R): List[R]`

But, a question now arises. Is that a "good" order, or should it be
`def foo(delegate: T => R)(data: List[T]): List[R]`

I guess the generalized form of my question would be the following: Given we need to define a function `f`, that operates on data `x1, x2, ..., xN`, using delegate functions `g1, g2, ..., gM` that operate on data, and functions `h1, h2, ..., hK` that do not operate on data, what is the preferred/correct order of parameter sets for function `f` and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct order is data first, functions second.

The first reason is that if `T` is a type parameter of your function, you will get better type inference this way:

```
scala> def foo[T](l: List[T])(f: T => T): Unit = ()
foo: [T](l: List[T])(f: T => T)Unit

scala> foo(List(1))(x => x + 1)

scala> def foo2[T](f: T => T)(l: List[T]): Unit = ()
foo2: [T](f: T => T)(l: List[T])Unit

scala> foo2(x => x + 1)(List(1))
<console>:13: error: missing parameter type
       foo2(x => x + 1)(List(1))
```

The second reason is that it looks nicer with anonymous functions. Compare

```
foo2[Int] { x =>
  x + 1
} (List(1)) // Meh
```

with

```
foo[Int](List(1)) { x =>
  x + 1
} // Wow
```